# How to print variable name in a function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm working with a large dataframe with many variables. All those variables have a label and labels. I'm trying to build a function where I automatically get the label, labels, table with NA's AND the original variable name (so that I know which label corresponds with which variable).

I've build the following function.

```
printattfun <- function(x){
  label <- attr(x, "label")
  labels <- attr(x, "labels")
  table <- table(x, useNA = "ifany")
  print(label)
  print(labels)
  print(table)
  }
```

This function allows me to get the label, labels and tables.
I use sapply to apply it to the desired columns:

```
sapply(X = df, FUN = printattfun)
```

The only thing that I cannot manage to create is that it also displays the variable name in the original df. I've tried to add this to my function

```
names(attr(x, "label") (which returns NULL)
colnames(x) (which also returns NULL)
```

Also I've read something about desparse and substitute and I've also tried to add this to my function:

```
nm <- deparse(substitute(x)); strsplit(nm, '\\[')
print(nm)
```

But this does also not work. Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the ``get()`` function

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and expected output to make this more clear? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)